# Access property/variable from unknown object

Tags: c#, list, object, properties

I have a list of 'object' that has different kinds of objects in it. I need to be able to edit/read a property of the objects that all of them have, but I don't know how to do that.

```
List<object> objects = new list<object>();
SomeObject obj;

objects.add(obj);

Int value = objects(0).somevariable;
```

But it obviously can't read 'somevariable' since the code doesn't know that the object has it. Is doing this possible since all the objects in the list has the variable 'somevariable'?

Also, I'm using XNA, but that probably doesn't make any difference.

Edit: Thanks everybody for your answers, I'll try them tomorrow when I get on my computer.

Comment: I hope that isn't possible, otherwise it would be too easy for someone to figure out all kinds of data going across a network.

Comment: This is a very common problem, the solution is to inherite all objects from one class that contains the needed property.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919699

Answer (score 4):

If you can modify those classes and make sense on your scenario, you could define a common interface

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
     int Somevariable { get; set;}
}
```

and let your classes implement this interface, then you will be able to create a generic list like this

```
var objects = new List<IMyInterface>();
int value = objects[0].Somevariable;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use reflection.

```
public static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
{
     return obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

(but of course use interface if possible :))

Answer (score 2):

Define an interface containing the methods and properties you want to access for all objects, let the classes of those objects implement this interface and declare your list as List. Or use reflection, but that's usually not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Make base class of which contains "somevariable", and BaseClasses list, so list[0].somevariable is possible to do.

```
class MyBaseClass
{
    public int SomeVariable{get;set;}
}
class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
.............
}

List<MyBaseClass> l=new List<MyBaseClass>();
l[0].SomeVariable=111;
```