# How can i use value of variable in Keys

Tags: c#, variables, key

How can i use the a value of a variable in the Keys. function?
like this:

```
string Key = "A";
if (Keys.M == e.Key)
{
    StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path));
    Key = read.ReadToEnd();
    Game.DisplayText(Key);
}

if (Keys.Key == e.Key)
{
    Game.DisplayText("It is working perfectly");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access an object property with a string variable that has the name of that property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919699/how-do-i-access-an-object-property-with-a-string-variable-that-has-the-name-of-t)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to [parse a value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx) for the [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) enum.

```
Keys key = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), "A");
```